# SceneDelegate's "continue" not called when launching App Clip from Xcode

Tags: ios14, apple-appclips

I am trying to test my app clip's url handler by running the app clip from Xcode. However the URL method handler (`SceneDelegate`'s `continue` method) never gets called, contrary to Apple's documentation [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/responding_to_invocations), which states:

> For a UIKit-based app clip and full app that support scene-based app
> life-cycle events, implement the callbacks defined in UISceneDelegate.
> For example, implement scene(_:continue:) callback to access the user
> activity object.
>
> For a UIKit-based app clip and full app that respond
> to app-based life-cycle events, implement the callbacks defined in
> UIApplicationDelegate. Be sure to implement the
> application(*:continue:restorationHandler:) callback, because you
> don’t have access to the NSUserActivity object in
> application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:).

- The app delegate does not implement the `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` method
- The app clip's scheme has the _XCApplClipURL parameter enabled and set to `https://fruits.com/check?fruit_name=bananas`
- The app clip's `Associated Domain` lists `appclips:fruits.com`
- The app clip's `SceneDelegate` is as follows

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {     
        // UGHH!!! Never gets called
        print("AppClip invocation url is : \(incomingURL)")
        
    }
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // OK!! This gets called
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return } 
    }
}
```

I have been banging my head on the walls for the last 2 days. What am I missing?

Note: I am using this [sample app available in github](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-apple-app-clips-sample-app), just modified the signing configuration to get the app clip to compile & run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `continue` method mentioned is only called when your app is invoked after it was previously opened. In order to get the value set in `_XCApplClipURL` the first time your app is launched, you need to use the second method you mentioned (`scene willConnectTo session`).

You can try something like this:

```
if let activity = connectionOptions.userActivities.filter({ $0.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb }).first {
  if let url = activity.webpageURL {
    print("incoming URL: \(url)")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your using AppsFlyer's public demo of App Clip and for highlighting this issue. I really appreciate it.

I can confirm you were doing great, this functionality was broken sometime after Beta 5.

Please follow and comment on this issue [here](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-apple-app-clips-sample-app/issues/1)

Comment: Hugo, the issue is fixed in the demo app. Please test. Thanks